# Having Different Problems Installing Passenger After Upgrading to Version 5 of the Apple Server App

Tags: macos, apache, server, passenger, osx-yosemite

I was successfully running Passenger 4.0.59 and version 4 of the Server App. I had a minor problem with 4.0.59 after updating to Server 5.0.4. I thought the problem was with the Server app so I decided to roll back my server to just before I updated the Server App. With Server 4.1.13 I was able to successfully upgrade and run Passenger 5.0.20.

At that time I was running the latest version of Yosemite on my Mac Mini Server. The Server app version 5.0.4 and 5.0.15 were released to run on Yosemite and El Capitan. Again I started having problems with Passenger. I uninstalled Passenger as directed in the instructions and started over.

When I installed both the Enterprise and Open Source versions of 5.0.21 I got errors. When I do the **passenger-config validate-install** command it says that Everything looks good as before. However now when I do the When I do the passenger-config validate-install command it says that Everything looks good as before. However now when I do the passenger-status command it has not started but gets the following error. According to the documentation this requirement is unique to version 5.x.x of Passenger.

```
XXXXXXXX$ rvmsudo passenger-status
ERROR: Phusion Passenger doesn't seem to be running. If you are sure that it is running, then the causes of this problem could be:

1. You customized the instance registry directory using Apache's PassengerInstanceRegistryDir option, Nginx's passenger_instance_registry_dir option, or Phusion Passenger Standalone's --instance-registry-dir command line argument. If so, please set the environment variable PASSENGER_INSTANCE_REGISTRY_DIR to that directory and run passenger-status again.
2. The instance directory has been removed by an operating system background service. Please set a different instance registry directory using Apache's PassengerInstanceRegistryDir option, Nginx's passenger_instance_registry_dir option, or Phusion Passenger Standalone's --instance-registry-dir command line argument.
 command it has not started but gets the following error.

    XXXXXXXX$ rvmsudo passenger-status
    ERROR: Phusion Passenger doesn't seem to be running. If you are sure that it is running, then the causes of this problem could be:

    1. You customized the instance registry directory using Apache's PassengerInstanceRegistryDir option, Nginx's passenger_instance_registry_dir option, or Phusion Passenger Standalone's --instance-registry-dir command line argument. If so, please set the environment variable PASSENGER_INSTANCE_REGISTRY_DIR to that directory and run passenger-status again.
    2. The instance directory has been removed by an operating system background service. Please set a different instance registry directory using Apache's PassengerInstanceRegistryDir option, Nginx's passenger_instance_registry_dir option, or Phusion Passenger Standalone's --instance-registry-dir command line argument.
```

I tried adding the following statements (one at a time) to the Apache config file according to the [documentation](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/#passengerinstanceregistrydir) but got the same error.

```
PassengerInstanceRegistryDir /tmp

PassengerInstanceRegistryDir /private/tmp
```

I decided to uninstall 5.0.21 and install the open source version of Passenger 4.0.60 thinking that would solve the problem. However when I try and execute **rvmsudo passenger-install-apache2-module** I get a green _Noreturn error which I'm not familiar with.

```
rm -f buildout/libev/libev.la
cd buildout/libev/ && make libev.la
/bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile cc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/Users/server1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@LightBeCorp_Rails42Ruby222/gems/passenger-4.0.60/ext/libev     -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fcommon -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -g -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -w -MT ev.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/ev.Tpo -c -o ev.lo /Users/server1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@LightBeCorp_Rails42Ruby222/gems/passenger-4.0.60/ext/libev/ev.c
libtool: compile:  cc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/Users/server1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@LightBeCorp_Rails42Ruby222/gems/passenger-4.0.60/ext/libev -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fcommon -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -g -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -w -MT ev.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/ev.Tpo -c /Users/server1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@LightBeCorp_Rails42Ruby222/gems/passenger-4.0.60/ext/libev/ev.c -o ev.o
/Users/server1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@LightBeCorp_Rails42Ruby222/gems/passenger-4.0.60/ext/libev/ev.c:970:42: error: '_Noreturn' keyword must precede function declarator
  ecb_inline void ecb_unreachable (void) ecb_noreturn;
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
  _Noreturn 
/Users/server1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@LightBeCorp_Rails42Ruby222/gems/passenger-4.0.60/ext/libev/ev.c:773:26: note: expanded from macro 'ecb_noreturn'
  #define ecb_noreturn   _Noreturn
                         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [ev.lo] Error 1
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (2): [cd buildout/libev/ && make libev.la...]
/Users/server1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@LightBeCorp_Rails42Ruby222/gems/passenger-4.0.60/build/common_library.rb:143:in `block in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => apache2 => buildout/agents/PassengerHelperAgent => buildout/libev/.libs/libev.a
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

--------------------------------------------

It looks like something went wrong
```

I've done web searches about problems with upgrading to El Capitan and/or the current version of the Server app but none of them are dealing with problems with the Passenger errors I'm getting.

Answer (score 0):

I posted my question in the Phusion Passenger Google Group. They suggested that I run `rvmsudo passenger-memory-stats`. This revealed that the Apache configuration changed with version 5 of the server app. I confirmed this by contacting the Apple Enterprise Support team. The new Apache config file for version 5 of the Server app is `/Library/Server/Web/Config/Proxy/apache_serviceproxy.conf`. I copied my passenger statements along with the virtual host include statement and was able to get Passenger 5.0.22 working.

Answer (score 0):

At some point I had gotten tired of the web server config file being overwritten, and noticed that all .conf files in the "other" (`/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/other/`) directory are loaded by default. Create a passenger.conf file (or whatever you'd like to call it) in that directory with your passenger config options and it will always be loaded and never overwritten.